# list all items in a table using ASP.NET entity framework

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio

How can I list all items in a table using ASP.NET entity framework?
Here is my controller code with an example how I would access a particular item property, the Index view of said controller is still empty: http://pastebin.com/gBqru7rK

I want to be able to list all items in the Movies table.

Comment: Pastebin link is no longer available, therefore this question should be closed.